# Time-to-event statistical test for toxicity within a 12-month time frame?

Tags: survival, biostatistics, clinical-trials, competing-risks

I am performing a retrospective study and this is my hypothesis: among patients with metastatic melanoma, antibiotic exposure within the 3 months prior to immunotherapy increases the risk of therapy-induced colitis within 12 months following the first infusion of immunotherapy.

This hypothesis is informed by basic science data.

I need to use a 12-month window, because biologically as you get further and further out from the antibiotics it becomes harder to really attribute any colitis to the antibiotics.

My suspicion is that I need to use time-to-event analysis, specifically competing risks because of the high disease-specific mortality rate (i.e. patients could die before they develop therapy-induced colitis).

However I don't know if this analysis would be valid because my "event" endpoint by definition can't occur after 12 months of follow up time. Basically any patient who doesn't have the toxicity or death by 12 months would automatically be a "no" for the event variable.

What is the best way to test whether the exposed group has a higher rate of therapy-induced colitis within 12 months? It would seem that basic chi-square would be biased because of the high competing risk rate.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Thinking about this more deeply, I wonder if the correct approach is to censor anyone who is alive without colitis at 1 year of follow up.